# How to generate headers for azure cosmos db to make rest api requests

Tags: azure, rest, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I want to get Docs from my azure cosmos db but I am getting unauthorized error and I know its related to resource id and resource type string format. Please help in constructing right string.

```python
import requests
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
from datetime import datetime
import urllib.parse
key = '<key>=='
now = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:00 GMT')
print(now)
payload = ('get\ndocs\ndbs/iot/colls/messages\n' + now + '\n\n').lower()


payload = bytes(((payload)),encoding='utf8')
key = base64.b64decode(key.encode('utf-8'))

signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(key, msg = payload, digestmod = 
hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()
print(signature)

authStr = urllib.parse.quote('type=master&ver=1.0&sig={}'.format(signature))
print("key = " ,authStr)

headers = {
'Authorization': authStr,
"x-ms-date": now,
"x-ms-version": "2017-02-22"
}
url = 'https://rpi.documents.azure.com/dbs/iot/colls/messages'
res = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
print(res.content)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please clarify your question a bit further by making the code minimal, describing the context, errors and warnings you obtained so far, .. For more guidance, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please generate a new key for your Cosmos DB account immediately. You included your current key in your code sample, essentially giving away access to the entire world. I edited it out of your question, but people with high enough rep can still get to it.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed there's an extra new line character in your payload (after `messages`)

```
payload = ('get\ndocs\ndbs\iot\colls\messages\n\n' + now + '\n\n').lower()
```

Moreover `resourceLink` also seems incorrect. You're using `\` instead of `/` in the resource link.

Can you try by changing it to:

```
payload = ('get\ndocs\ndbs/iot/colls/messages\n' + now + '\n\n').lower()
```

Also, please change your `url` from `url = 'https://rpi.documents.azure.com/dbs'` to `url = 'https://rpi.documents.azure.com/dbs/iot/colls/messages'`.

and see if that makes the difference.

Comment: '{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"The input authorization token can\'t serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: \'get\\ndbs\\n\\ntue, 13 aug 2019 10:33:00 gmt\\n\\n\'\\r\\nActivityId: d8cbbadd-483d-42c7-90bc-bd6adb7fc0d7, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.5.1"}'

Comment: Can you try by changing your url to `'https://rpi.documents.azure.com/dbs/iot/colls/messages'`? This is because resource link in your authorization header is `dbs/iot/colls/messages` but you're requesting another resource in your url.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the latest code you're using? Or create a new gist on Github: https://gist.github.com/?

Comment: b'{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"The input authorization token can\'t serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: \'get\\ncolls\\ndbs/iot/colls/messages\\ntue, 13 aug 2019 11:30:00 gmt\\n\\n\'\\r\\nActivityId: 55c0ad97-2614-403a-995c-a4b9d35b5784, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.5.1"}'
PS C:\Users\disha.shrivastava\Desktop>

Comment: @DishaShrivastava - please refrain from posting all your updates and error messages here as comments under Gaurav's question. These need to be part of your original question, as an edit. Aside from being in the wrong place, they are very difficult to read as unformatted-text in a comment.

Comment: @GauravMantri  How do I fetch data from cosmos db (Mongo) using REST API ?